# Is it possible to pass arguments to setup.py while creating own .whl file?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, setuptools, setup.py

I often update my own libs using in my projects and i want to automate it so i wrote a script which calls command which builds a .whl lib by `os.system` and `setup.py` module gets build params by `sys.argv` but it returns as response:

```
invalid command name '1.0.9'
```

command i call: `python ./LoggerLib/setup.py bdist_wheel 1.0.9`
`sys.argv`: `['./LoggerLib/setup.py', 'bdist_wheel', '1.0.9']`

The only way i know at this moment is to write the data to other file and read it in setup.py but it isn't elegant.

Do you know how to do it in another way?

Comment: You could pass configuration via environment variables. For example `PROJECT_VERSION='1.0.9' python setup.py`. And read this `PROJECT_VERSION` environment variable in your `setup.py`: `setuptools.setup(version=os.getenv('PROJECT_VERSION'), ...)`.